# SceneBuilder not loading in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, scenebuilder

Scene Builder does not open in my Intellij. I've tried different JDK versions, but I just cant get it to load up in my IDE. It was working before I had to reinstall my OS. I don't get an error or anything, the Scene Builder window is just blank. It works if I run it standalone though.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.1. Using JDK 11 and Scene Builder for JDK 11. I tried with JDK 14 and I still get the same issue. I attached an image of the screen I get.[image]

Any help? Intellij asked me to download the Scene Builder kit, then it asked me to download JavaFX. I did. Then I ended up here. JavaFX was included as a global library though so I didn't quite understand that.

What should I do?

Answer (score 10):

You should go to `file` -> `settings` -> `plugins` search for `javaFX` and install `JavaFX Runtime for Plugins`.

Restart again and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 4):

## 2023 Answer

I am currently using IntelliJ Ultimate.

- Build #: 223.8617.56
- Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.25 aarch64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

To fix the missing SceneBuilder issue, I completely disabled the JavaFX Runtime for Plugins plugin and restarted IntelliJ.

When I did that, I received 2 banners to install JavaFX and the proper JDK.
[image]

Comment: I did not receive the banners to install JavaFX or a JDK but it still solved the problem for me. I also deleted several JavaFX plugins that were installed: JavaFX Tools, FXMLHelper, and JavaFX Runtime Demo.

Comment: This is correct, I get 2 banners about install SceneBuiler kit and java fx kit..
worked now.

@Phil did you forget to set the path to sceneBuiler?

please check this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/opening-fxml-files-in-javafx-scene-builder.html

Answer (score 2):

You can run the SceneBuilder from outside Intellij and simply select your FXML, which works better in some cases, because there are some problems with the BuildIn Version (at least on Windows)

You can download it from Gluon.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However this doesn't address my problem at all. I know its better to run it standalone. But I shouldn't have to do that if I want to have a quick preview of the file (which I'm forced to do right now).

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was 'Settings> Plugins> search JavaFX' to enable and disable this plugin, then restart intellij idea